# Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, real-numbers

> Which of the following sets are compact?
>
> $1.\{({1\over n},{1\over m})\in \mathbb R^2:m,n\in \mathbb Z\}\bigcup \{(0,0)\}\bigcup \{({1\over n},0):n\in \mathbb Z\}\bigcup \{(0,{1\over n}): n\in \mathbb Z\}$
>
> $2.\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: |x|+|2y|+|3z|\le 1\}$
>
> $3.\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3:x^2+2y^2-3z^2=1\}$
>
> $4.\{(x_1,x_2,....,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n:x_1+x_2+x_3+.....+x_n=0\}$

**Option $4$** is clearly unbounded so not compact.

For **option $3$**, $x^2+2y^2=1+3z^2$ so the set , is unbounded for arbitrarily large values of $z$ will take up arbitrarily large values of $x$ and $y$ so unbounded.

**Option $2$** is bounded since the equation is basically sum of three positive numbers less than $1$.How do I show that it is closed as well?

For **Option $1$**,the set is bounded and  I can see the set $ \{(0,0)\}\bigcup \{({1\over n},0):n\in \mathbb Z\}\bigcup \{(0,{1\over n}): n\in \mathbb Z\}$  is closed itself and is a set of limit points of the set $\{({1\over n},{1\over m})\in \mathbb R^2:m,n\in \mathbb Z\}$. Now if only I could show that those are the only limit points the set $\{({1\over n},{1\over m})\in \mathbb R^2:m,n\in \mathbb Z\}$  can have then I would be sure that it was **compact.**  How do I prove that? Thank you.

Comment: For showing that $2$ is closed you can use sequences and the fact that $x \to \vert x \vert$ is continuous.For $1$ recall that limit points are limits of subsequences.

Comment: For 2) let (x,y,z) be such the g=|x|+|2y|+|3z| > 1.  Let e = g-1.  show (x,y,z) can't be a limit point.  1)  remember proving {1/n} has only 1 limit point and it is 0?  You do this the exact same way except there a lot more cases to test.

Comment: It might (or might not) be easier to prove 1) is compact by the open cover def.  Let there be an open cover.  Pick a open set containing (0,0).  There's a only finitely many points not in that set.  Pick one set in the cover for each remaining point.